# Passing a string by reference and manipulate the string

Tags: rust

I am trying to pass a string by reference and manipulate the string in the function:

```
fn manipulate(s: &mut String) {                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  // do some string manipulation, like push
  s.push('3');  // error: type `&mut collections::string::String` 
                // does not implement any method in scope named `push`
}

fn main() {
  let mut s = "This is a testing string".to_string();
  manipulate(&s);          
  println!("{}", s);       
}
```

I have looked at examples on [borrowing](http://rustbyexample.com/borrow.html) and [mutibility](http://rustbyexample.com/borrow/mut.html).  Also tried `(*s).push('3')`, but got

```
error: type `collections::string::String` does not implement any method in scope named `push`
```

I'm sure there's something obvious I'm missing or perhaps more reference material to read, but I'm not sure how to proceed.  Thanks!

Comment: The change `push_char` -> `push` must be relatively recent, since I don't recall encountering it the last time I used that part of String functionality. What version are you using (if nightly, from what date)?

Comment: The version I am using is `rustc 0.12.0-nightly (740905042 2014-09-29 23:52:21 +0000)`

Comment: To correct the previous comment I made.  I tried the same code on a different machine, which has `rustc 0.12.0-nightly (740905042 2014-09-29 23:52:21 +0000)`.  The error that result is actually a lot more informative: `error: cannot borrow immutable dereference of `&`-pointer as mutable`.  Basically it is exactly as @IdolfHatler described!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code works with a slight modification on the newest version of rustc.

```
fn manipulate(s: &mut String) {                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  s.push('3');
}

fn main() {
  let mut s = "This is a testing string".to_string();
  manipulate(&mut s);          
  println!("{}", s);       
}
```